# Insert unique and non-unique values MySQL in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `board_positions` which contains the positions (e.g. `president, vice-president, member, etc.`). I'm referencing the ID of these positions to another table called `board_members`.

What I'm struggling with is how to make this table `board_members` accept only one `president` and many `members`?

I tried to do it with `unique` constraint, but this constraint makes `board_members` accept a unique position for each member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write a trigger that would check for number of president positions.

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_board_members_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON board_members
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE president_id INT;
    DECLARE presidents_count INT;

    SET president_id = 1; -- change here to reflect the actual value

    IF (NEW.position_id = president_id) THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO presidents_count
        FROM board_members
        WHERE position_id = president_id;

        IF (presidents_count >= 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Maximum number of presidents reached.';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

UPDATE trigger will look similar.

Comment: it works like a charm.. I was struggling with this issue for days before I asked for help.

thanks a lot. you made my day.